# Why QBFC is throwing exception with message "String too long" instead of response containing error code?

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

I have a C# program that is using QBFCv13 to create 46 customers in QuickBooks Pro 2014. 
When the program runs, I get an exception with message "String too long.". I am guessing it's probably caused by one of the customer name is too long so I test the program to create 2 customers with one long name. This time I didn't get an exception. I get a response list with one response containing error code and the other response without error.

I am confused. Why in certain case I get an exception? The message doesn't contain any more message than "String too long". I am wondering if there is something else I can do to figure what is causing this "String too long" error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling verbose logging and see if it tells you what the error is.

https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/177198-troubleshooting-sdk-issues